# Intellij console output shows lot of unecessary stuff

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there any way to disable the below stuff in my console output:

9:11:50 PM: Executing task 'Runner.main()'...

:compileJava
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes
:Runner.main()

**Learning Dagger Basics 0**

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
9:11:51 PM: Task execution finished 'Runner.main()'.

The portion in Bold is my output but i end up seeing it wrapped around stuff i dont want to see.

Can someone please guide me if there is a way possible to disable those

Answer (score 0):

You could disable "Delegate IDE build/run action to Gradle" option in "Settings | Build... | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner"

Comment: If i disable that , then my project utilizing dagger doesnt compile.
The component throws up an error saying symbol not found

Comment: There is no option to configure Gradle output. Feel free to vote for the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191119